# What does the TAB keyword do in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used some code from the internet to model some of my queries for a stored procedure.  It uses the keyword TAB and I have no idea what it does.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT * INTO #DailyReport
FROM
    (SELECT a.customer,b.cust_name, opendt, txdate [DATE], salesamt 
    from Daily a left outer join customer b on a.customer =b.customer 
    where txdate between @begin and @end)  TAB

SELECT * INTO #DailyTX
FROM
    (SELECT customer, txdate [DATE], SALESTX from Daily 
    where txdate between @begin and @end)  TAB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a keyword, this is an alias.  The user left out the AS keyword (which is legal SQL and allowed)

```
SELECT * INTO #DailyTX
FROM
  (SELECT customer, txdate [DATE], SALESTX from Daily 
   where txdate between @begin and @end) AS TAB
```

SQL Server requires that sub-queries are aliased so the writter just picked the first 3 letters of TABLE I guess.  TMP might have been clearer.  It essentially is a variable name.

Comment: Thank you.  It confused the heck out of me :)